# how to view exception backtrace in exception_handler gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

we are using rails 6 with 'exception_handler', '~> 0.8.0.0'.

we able to configure this gem and able to show error message but we like to get an error backtrace but we not see an option to get backtrace details for and exception.

can someone help me to understand this gem support to provide backtrace?

if you know any other gem which supports backtrace with a custom error page with rails 6 then let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and it works.  in exception_handler gem documentation, I do not see any information for backtrace but I found the bugs section that they discuss for the same and I see they use `exception.trace` to get a full backtrace information

Comment: Although this answers your question it does so in a way that is not very helpful to others who may have the same issue. I recommend providing a detailed explanation of how to use `exception.trace` and why it specifically answers your question, so that others can more easily implement a similar solution.